# Eclipse graphic environment for html/java designg

Tags: java, html, eclipse, web

Does Eclipse have a graphic environment in order to help website html/java development?

If not, how could I install a plugin on Eclipse or which other coding environment would be better to code + designing a website.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe thats something you are searching for: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Web Development perspectives is very useful for development JSF.

Answer (score 0):

For writing java programs that use a GUI I would recommend installing NetBeans (https://netbeans.org/) as it features an interactive environment for viewing and editing your program and it is free.

For HTML you could use Dreamweaver which is also free, or you could install Expression web (http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=36179) which again is free. They are lots of free HTML IDE's around if you google it.

Answer (score 0):

To get HTML GUI, you can try this. Right click your "html file" in eclipse then go for "open with" then select "web page editor". Now you may get GUI design for HTML page.